# Open Extrernal HTML page inside Angular Dialog

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-dialog

I am working on single Page application with Angular and Bootstrap.

At the top of the application there is button HELP. When user will click, Popup should be open with Help Content which is another HTML file.

Using ngDialog i am able to display the external Help Html file inside the dialog. But this HELP HTML file contains few hyperlink for navigation. So when i clicked those hyperlink , the main application's url is getting changed  instead of changing in the HELP  HTML page inside the dialog.

Any reference or help on this issue ?

Comment: That's the behavior of hyper link. The target URL of the hyper link will display in the URL.

Comment: What you want exactly?

Comment: I want to open a help webapge on the dailog from my main page. Navigation on help webpage shoult not change the main page URL. It should be work inside the dialog only ..

Comment: In that case show the help message in that pop-up itself